# Garry's Mod RunConsoleCommand() does not work correctly

Tags: lua, quotes, garrys-mod

I want to let some friends connect to my server just by clicking a simple button in the Garry's Mod menu. To do that I have added some code to the mainmenu.lua file of Garry's mod. The Button and all other things work, only the `RunConsoleCommand("connect", "mycoolgmodserverip.com")` fails... In the Console I can find the error `Bad server address ("mycoolgmodserverip.com")` like when I would type `connect "mycoolgmodserverip.com"` in the console. But I have to remove the quotes... It does not work with `RunConsoleCommand("connect", 'mycoolgmodserverip.com')` too.. Do you have any idea?

Comment: What error do you get from the single-quoted version? The same thing? And if you run `connect "someserver.com"` on the command line yourself you get the error with the quotes but `connect someserver.com` doesn't give you that error with the quotes (pick some string that triggers that `Bad server address` error to test with)?

Comment: connect "someserver.com" makes the same error and with single quotes too... it only works with connect someserver.com (without quotes), but how could I write that in my code?

Comment: You see whichever of single or double quotes you used on the command line (or in `RunConsoleCommand`) in the error? Or does the error always use double quotes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [Garry's Mod source code](https://github.com/garrynewman/garrysmod/blob/master/garrysmod/html/js/menu/control.Servers.js#L110), you may call `JoinServer` in the menu state.

Examples:

`JoinServer(address)`
`JoinServer("myepicserverip.com")`